# SyntaxError on importing from local directory

Tags: python

Im learning how to use python with psycopg2 for postgres and honestly I don't know why I'm having this issue now, all I did was move a couple of files into a new subfolder and now reversing the changes doesn't remove the error.

I've tried moving the file in and out of different subfolders as well, using different names. This is the first time I've had something like this.

Here's some code that I'm pulling my hair out on:

```
import psycopg2 as database
import config from config 

def connect():
    connect = None
    try:
        params = config()

        print('Attempting to connect to database.')
        connect = database.connect(**params)


    except (Exception,database.DatabaseError) as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if connect is not None:
            connect.close()
            print('Database connection closed.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

Comment: What's the error that you're seeing?

Comment: Show error message

Comment: Also, make sure that you have `__init__.py` file in the project directories.

Comment: And that you're using the correct interpreter (2 vs 3).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In the future, for debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including the full error message, which will help you and us understand the issue better. The problem here was basically a typo, so I'm voting to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

The error you see will be something similar to:

```
    import config from config
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The key is that it is a `SyntaxError`, which is roughly the Python interpreter saying "You have written something that is not even Python". It is an error in even **reading** the source code you have given, before the interpreter even tries to make sense of it.

What this means is that changing the structure of directories, moving files etc. will have no effect on this kind of error. You have to look carefully where the error message tells you (i.e. line 2), and figure out why it is not valid Python.

In this case, you must change the second line from `import config from config` to `from config import config`.

Because `import ... from ...` is not valid Python.